# Free Invisible image counter in the html page

Tags: images, visitors

I need to track number of visits of my publication, but site allows only to insert images, and no javascript.

I would like to insert white 1x1 pixel image.

Are the any internet services which provide such functionality and count number of visits via such approach?

P.S. I am not sure that this site is correct place to ask my question. In such case I will be very appreciate if you direct me to right location

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately, Google Analytics does exactly the same thing, however, the image URL is created using Javascript.

If you really, really wanted to use Google Analytics for your site, (albeit with limited functionality) you might take a look at [Troubleshooting The Tracking Code](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingTroubleshooting.html) to see how the image URL works - here's the bare minimum to push data to Google:

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?
utmhn=<hostname>&
utmac=<google acct id>
```

So if your hostname were "mydomain.com" and your Google account ID were "UA-123ABC-99" then you could use the following image URL on your site:

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmhn=mydomain.com&utmac=UA-123ABC-99
```

This limited implementation should allow you to track per-page statistics, unique/returning visitors, and more (you'll be missing any Javascript-enabled features, though - including event tracking).

Answer (score 1):

I believe [Extreme Tracking](http://extremetracking.com/?free) uses only an image - it's free and the stats are quite useful. You could resize/hide the button, however, there is a chance it could be against their TOS to do that.

Comment: I already implemented simple counter myself. It is really unexpected that I was not able to find what I wanted - this is so simple functionality.